# Citations in Latex not working

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am not able to make citations. I set up my `.bib` file, my `\bibiography{path}` and `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, I compile my file stuuf so latex bibtex latex latex and I only get `[?]` were the reference should be and a warning:

> `` LaTeX Warning: Citation `blablabla' on page n undefined on input line 214. ``

Any ideas?
My example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

Citations are fun \cite{blumEcologyRiverAlgae1956}

\section{References}

\bibliography{path to/Mylibrary}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Example from my .bib file

```
@article{blumEcologyRiverAlgae1956,
  title = {The Ecology of River Algae},
  volume = {22},
  issn = {0006-8101, 1874-9372},
  doi = {10.1007/BF02872474},
  language = {en},
  number = {5},
  journal = {The Botanical Review},
  author = {Blum, John L.},
  month = may,
  year = {1956},
  pages = {291-341},
  file = {path to the file}
}
```

I also get the notification:

> `` Process started I couldn't open file name `Mylibrary.aux' Process exited normally ``

when I compile my `.bib` file. Not sure if this is relevant because when I tried citing on a new empty document  (so not my main document) it worked once but then never again.

Comment: First up, use a forward slash on that file name, and no `.bib` extension. Secondly, bibtex only includes those you have explicitly cited (unless told othervise). Thirdly, remember latex, bibtex, latex, latex

Comment: I used the wrong slash  on my example, sorry, I removed the .bib but its still not working, and I am compiling latex, bibtex latex latex, i changed my text so that it should be clearer now :).  The references i used are also in my .bib file if thats what you meant.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to compile the `bib` file? It does sound like you might be. The commands all get run on the basename of the latex file: so if your document is called `foo.tex` then it's `latex foo.tex`, `bibtex foo`, `latex foo.tex`

Comment: Please show us a [minimal but working example with bib-file](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/9057). Currently we are not able to reproduce the problem with the shown code. Currently we even do not now, whether  you've used the correct cite key or whether there are mistakes in your `.bib`-file.

Comment: Related (and maybe duplicate): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/9057

Comment: also, `...` three dots, where exactly is that `.bib` file? If it is one level up, then it should be two dots. You should see this in the log file from bibtex. (it has extension `.blg` which Windows hides by default).

Comment: no the ... represents the rest of the path to the .bib file, which is in the same folder as my main document.

Comment: Off-Topic: Please have a look at https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/ to find out, how to format your questions.

Comment: Your example does work an does not show any error. So please show us the BibTeX-log-file (the one with the extension `.blg`). Maybe just the `path to/Mylibrary` is wrong.

Comment: Or maybe the you run BibTeX with the wrong file-name, e.g., if your main file is names `foo.tex` you have to run "`bibtex foo`" not "`bibtex Mylibrary`".

Comment: I was doing that (and I really feel stupid for it) It now kind of works, I get some warnings  file missing years and things like that but I can I just have to search for that particular file and add the year. Thank you!